# puppeteer throw error when run in lambda function:- protocol error (Page.printToPDF): Printing failed

Tags: javascript, lambda, puppeteer

I have deplyod the puppeteer function on aws lambda
and I used this function to generate pdf at multiple places but on one place i am continusly getting this error

> (Page.printToPDF): Printing failed
> at /var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:217:63
> at new Promise ()
> at CDPSession.send (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:216:16)
> at Page.createPDFStream (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Page.js:1968:43)
> at Page.pdf (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/Page.js:1996:37)
> at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/app.js:92:28)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5

On other places it is wokring fine
I have used the latest version also and still getting this error

uptill the page.pdf every thing work fine and after this i got the upper error

````
```// render pdf
    const pdf = await page.pdf({
      scale: body.pdfCoordinator?.scale,
      margin: body.pdfCoordinator?.margin || { top: '9.5mm', bottom: '9.5mm', left: '6mm', right: '6mm' },
      format: 'A4',
      landscape: body.pdfCoordinator?.landscape || false,
      printBackground: true,
      displayHeaderFooter: body.pdfCoordinator?.displayHeaderFooter !== undefined ? body.pdfCoordinator.displayHeaderFooter : true,
      headerTemplate: getHeaderFooter(),
      footerTemplate: getHeaderFooter(),
      width: '27.3cm',
      height: '30.61cm',
    })
  
    // clear and close
````

after this if got the upper protocol error
I tried to search about it but there is no solution provided

please help to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

I belive when puppeteer is used/initilized with puppeteer.connect it is not able to used its all the functionality so i change it to puppetter.launch and it fixes the issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I spent ages trying to fix this so thought I'd post to help anyone else.

I got the error '(Page.printToPDF): Printing failed' for me it was Lambda memory. I doubled the ephemeral memory and it now works really well, generating large images with no issue from my Lambda

Hope this helps